# Custom jQuery plugin shows error

Tags: jquery

I created my own tiny jQuery plugin to change an image src on hover

```
$.fn.hover_image = function () {
$(this).each(function () {
    var img = $(this).children('img');
    var oldImgSrc = img.attr('src');
    var newImgSrc = oldImgSrc.substr(0, oldImgSrc.lastIndexOf('.')) + '_hover.png';

    $(this).hover(function () {
        img.fadeOut('fast', function () {
            img.attr('src', newImgSrc);
            img.fadeIn('fast');
        });
    },

    function () {
        img.fadeOut('fast', function () {
            img.attr('src', oldImgSrc);
            img.fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
    return $(this);
});
};
```

the plugin works properly but I get error in console
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lastIndexOf' of undefined`
What's wrong with the code ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: It would appear that you have a broken `<img />` tag with no `src` attribute

Comment: If you get this error, then `oldImgSrc` is `undefined`, which means `$(this).children('img');` returns an empty set or the fist selected element doesn't have a `src` attribute.

Comment: thanks a lot for comments, I just tried to use my function for wrong image.